# Find out if my computers have location (GPS) hardware

Tags: windows-7, windows, geolocation, gps

How can I find out if my (Windows 7) desktop and laptop computers have hardware that can provide the current geolocation?

Comment: if they have wifi they can geolocate

Comment: It's extremely unlikely your laptop has a gps

Comment: ...but you don't need GPS to do geolocation, so long as you can see wifi, or a phone mast [if the device is capable]. My desktop's geolocate is just as accurate as my phone's, one has GPS, the other doesn't.